# How to generate meta tags for Twitter player card

Tags: meta-tags, twitter, twitter-card

I am using flow player as video player in my website. Twitter supports player cards which will require some tags to be inserted in our pages provided by twitter. I did the same as mentioned by twitter but not able get approval. They are telling that My website has wrong meta tags. Can some one tell me whats the wrong with my twitter player card.?

the following are the meta tags i have inserted.

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="player">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@PSPKfans_in">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@PSPKfans_in">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Pawan Kalyan In India Today Magazine Preview">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="This Video Gives the Preview of the book. Pawan Kalyan In India Today Magazine Preview">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://www.pspkfans.in/pawankalyanininidatoday.png">
<meta name="twitter:player" content="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf">
<meta name="twitter:player:stream" content="https://www.pspkfans.in/pawankalyaninindiatoday.mp4">
<meta name="twitter:player:stream:content_type" content="">
<meta name="twitter:player:height" content="960">
<meta name="twitter:player:width" content="964">
<meta name="twitter:player:stream:content_type" content="video/mp4">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="www.PSPKfans.in">
```

Answer (score 2):

The twitter:player value has to be on a secure server, ie `https`

Twitter's documentation is pretty bad, but they ask for the twitter:player value to be "HTTPS URL to iframe player".  I assume this means the URL of a page which plays the video and has no other content surrounding it, so that it can be placed within an iframe (as opposed to the link you give to the empty flowplayer swf file).